# Error: No named parameter with the name'onPointerPanZoomUpdate'

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I am trying to develop a chart but what happens when make flutter run the code I have Failed to compile the application. My code has no errors but cannot be run. Am I wrong in compiling this code? How to check this problem. Can anyone help with my code?

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late TooltipBehavior _tooltipBehavior;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tooltipBehavior = TooltipBehavior(enable: true);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('afadff'),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: Container(
                child: SfCartesianChart(
                    // Enables the tooltip for all the series in chart
                    tooltipBehavior: _tooltipBehavior,
                    // Initialize category axis
                    primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(),
                    series: <ChartSeries>[
              // Initialize line series
              LineSeries<ChartData, String>(
                  // Enables the tooltip for individual series
                  enableTooltip: true,
                  dataSource: [
                    // Bind data source
                    ChartData('Jan', 35),
                    ChartData('Feb', 28),
                    ChartData('Mar', 34),
                    ChartData('Apr', 32),
                    ChartData('May', 40)
                  ],
                  xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.x,
                  yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.y)
            ]))));
  }
}

class ChartData {
  ChartData(this.x, this.y);
  final String x;
  final double? y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find the `onPointerPanZoomUpdate` on the snippet you've provided. The error indicates that onPointerPanZoomUpdate can't be found. The `Listener` callback **onPointerPanZoomUpdate** has been available since [Flutter 3.3](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/trackpad-gestures#description-of-change). If you're using an older version of Flutter, you need to run `flutter upgrade` on the terminal to upgrade your Flutter version.